# Angular 9 Typescript fullCalendar Validation for previous date - date in the past cannot be selected

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, fullcalendar

I am trying to create a validator in angular 9 app using fullCalendar. A date in the past cannot be selected. I have seen quite a few posts about this in relation to javascript but not Angular/typescript.

I have learnt that to find a current date I can use the below function in Angular:

```
today: number = Date.now();
```

I have the below in my ts form validation (doesn't work):

```
eventDate:['',Validators.required,(c: AbstractControl) => (new Date(c.value).getTime() < Date.now() ? { invalid: true } : null)],
```

I am aware of the option of using the below fullCalendar functionality, although I want my users to see their previous appointments and so I would like a validator that advises users that a date in the past cannot be booked:

```
 validRange:function(nowDate){
       return{
        start:nowDate,
       }
     }
```

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: If you aren't using moment.js, I would suggest trying that.  moment has great date comparison functions which make it easy to achieve what you are trying to achieve.  You can read about it here: https://momentjs.com

Comment: @Farasi78 https://github.com/you-dont-need/You-Dont-Need-Momentjs

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the result you want to reach is to make unable to click past dates, you can arrange the functions called when this two outputs of fullcalendar are fired: `(dateClick)` (this output fires the value of a single day selection) or `(select)` (this output fires the value of a multiple day selection) in this way:

**mycomponent.component.html**

```
<full-calendar
 #calendar
 [plugins]="somevalue"
 [header]="somevalue"
 [events]="somevalue"
 (dateClick)="handleDateClick($event)"
</full-calendar>
```

**mycomponent.component.ts**

```
handleDateClick(event) {
   if(new Date(event.dateStr).getTime() >= Date.now()) {
     //do something
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that your full date value from a time value. try converting the value either date or time than your logic will work.

use datepipe to convert the date and time values to your preference

if you want to subtract Date:

```
this.datePipe.transform(new Date(c.value), 'yyyy-MM-dd') - this.datePipe.transform(new Date(today), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

if you want to subtract time;

```
this.datePipe.transform(new Date(c.value), 'HH:mm') - this.datePipe.transform(new Date(today), 'HH:mm');
```